# How Do Draw Curved Lines From Point To Point Without SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I tried drawing curved lines from point to point with SVG with HTML&CSS but it is so confusing and just seems so outdated honestly. I couldn't find way to use % instead of absolute pixels or just anything honestly. What would you guys use to draw curved lines?(I attached an image)

Refer to IMG.

So I want to be drawn from point to point one by one and then undrawn one by one. I'm not asking to write my code, just point me in the right direction, please!

[image]

Comment: Well, is canvas allowed? Is so, try html5 canvas

Comment: Take a look at [HTML5 Canvas](https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-bezier-curves/)